# which is best from this xml or json to use in web application all the devices

Tags: xml, json

I want to know that which technology is best use in web application desktop, mobile etc from this xml or json

Comment: This question is going to be closed because it is way too vague - different scenarios require different solutions, you can't be this general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion JSON is easier to parse on the client (Javascript), and more concise (smaller size) so unless you really need to output XML for legacy reasons, go with JSON.

(The question does not provide a lot of context so the answer's general too!)